# find string with quotes and double quotes in all oracle packages

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

I am trying to find a query which will return all the string inside all the packages and procedures like `like '2%'`. For example in dynamic query

`WHEN SUBSTR(S.project,0,1) LIKE ''2%'' THEN ''newProject''`

and like in normal query

`WHERE B.project LIKE '2%'`

I tried with this query

```
select *
  from user_source u
 where u.type in ('FUNCTION', 'PACKAGE','PACKAGE BODY', 'TRIGGER','PROCEDURE')
   and upper(u.text) like upper('%LIKE%')
```

But I am unable to find a query which can give a proper result for `like '2%'` in both dynamic and static query.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic and static query. Are you referring to `execute immediate` in procedures/triggers?

Comment: yes, `execute immediate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example: when dealing with single quotes you have to escape, it is simpler to use the "q" quoting mechanism.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return number is
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    select count(*)
  5      into l_cnt
  6      from emp
  7      where empno like '7%';
  8    return l_cnt;
  9  end;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

    F_TEST
----------
        12

SQL> select *
  2  from user_source
  3  where lower(text) like '%' || q'[like '7%']' ||'%';

NAME       TYPE               LINE TEXT
---------- ------------ ---------- ------------------------------
F_TEST     FUNCTION              7     where empno like '7%';

SQL>
```